# on rapidjson, encode just a number to string then decode it

Tags: c++, c, json, parsing, rapidjson

using **rapidjson**, how can i encode a number to json format? i have 123.321, i want to convert it to "123.321", then save it in a file. later using json convert it back to 123.321.
i don't want to use Document which saves as like "{"tag":"value"}", i want it to be saved as just a "value", then be converted back.

i have the following code to convert number to "number":

```
Value v(123);
StringBuffer mybuffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> mywriter(mybuffer);
v.Accept(mywriter);
const char* myjson = mybuffer.GetString();
```

how to convert it back? is the following a solution? i don't want to use handler!

```
Reader reader;           
StringStream ss(myjson); 
reader.Parse(ss, handler);
```

thanks for the upcoming helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer after digging into google:

to encode a number to json using [rapidjson](http://rapidjson.org/):

```
Value v(123.321);
StringBuffer mybuffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> mywriter(mybuffer);
v.Accept(mywriter);
const char* myjson = mybuffer.GetString();
```

now *myjson* has "123.321" as its value.
then to decode *myjson* to a number:

```
Document d;
d.Parse(myjson); // myjson is "123.321"
assert(d.IsNumber());
value = d.GetDouble(); // now the value is 123.321
```

as simple as it gets.